# Identify columns where records have different values

Tags: sql

I have a table where most of the columns have the same value in all records. I want to find those columns where there is more than 1 possible value for that column.

Consider the data below:

| A | B | C | D | E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 44 | 32 |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 45 | 33 |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 46 | 34 |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 47 | 35 |

I want to write a query that will determine that columns A, B and C have the same value in all records and D and E have different values. Then output the names of columns D and E.

Comment: Can you also _specify_ the expected result. And add a tag for the dbms used. And show us your current query attempt.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to know all columns in advance.

Than count all unique value in column:

```
SELECT
   (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(A)) FROM table GROUP BY A) AS A,
   (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(B)) FROM table GROUP BY B) AS B,
   ... Repeat for other columns ...
```

Now you will have output as follows:

| A | B | C | D | E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 4 | 4 |

Comment: Note that `DISTINCT` isn't a function, it's a _set quantifier_. Simply write `COUNT(DISTINCT A)` to make code clearer.

Comment: @jarlh That is code readability part. For me it's more readable to have `()`, but it does not change anything

Comment: Yes, and you can even do `SELECT ((COUNT(DISTINCT(((A))))))`.

Comment: BTW, your query raises an error, see https://dbfiddle.uk/72oWC7uz. Is the second query what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

You can try with this:

```
  SELECT D, E
    FROM MyTable 
   WHERE (select count(distinct A) from MyTable) = 1
     AND (select count(distinct B) from MyTable) = 1
     AND (select count(distinct C) from MyTable) = 1
     AND (select count(distinct D) from MyTable) > 1
     AND (select count(distinct E) from MyTable) > 1;

     D          E
    44         32
    45         33
    46         34
    47         35
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can select the distinct values along with the count how often that value occurs:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a, count(*) FROM table GROUP BY a;
```

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL you can run

```
SELECT CONCAT(
    'SELECT ',
    COLUMN_NAME AS clmname,
    ' FROM yourtable',
    ' WHERE MAX(',
    COLUMN_NAME,
    ') > MIN(',
    COLUMN_NAME,
    ') UNION'
)
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'yourschema' and TABLE_NAME = 'yourtable';
```

which will generate something like

```
SELECT A AS clmname FROM yourtable WHERE MAX(A) > MIN(A) UNION
SELECT B AS clmname FROM yourtable WHERE MAX(B) > MIN(B) UNION
SELECT C AS clmname FROM yourtable WHERE MAX(C) > MIN(C) UNION
SELECT D AS clmname FROM yourtable WHERE MAX(D) > MIN(D) UNION
SELECT E AS clmname FROM yourtable WHERE MAX(E) > MIN(E) UNION
```

So, let's use it as a subquery:

```
SELECT clmname
FROM (
    SELECT A AS clmname FROM yourtable WHERE MAX(A) > MIN(A) UNION
    SELECT B AS clmname FROM yourtable WHERE MAX(B) > MIN(B) UNION
    SELECT C AS clmname FROM yourtable WHERE MAX(C) > MIN(C) UNION
    SELECT D AS clmname FROM yourtable WHERE MAX(D) > MIN(D) UNION
    SELECT E AS clmname FROM yourtable WHERE MAX(E) > MIN(E)
) t
```

You can do it in other RDBMS systems as well, the logic stays the same, the resources to use vary from RDBMS to RDBMS.